# Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery() and StringTokenizer

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I want to do something like that:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(getCompletedAnswers, "$");
                while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){

                    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    rs = st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO "+db+".answersTable(`answer`) VALUES ('"+tokenizer.nextToken()+"')");

                }
```

But it gives me an error  `Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().`

As I read in documentation that I have to use `executeUpdate()` I'm doing it:

```
rs = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO "+db+".answersTable(`answer`) VALUES ('"+tokenizer.nextToken()+"')");
```

and it tells me: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to ResultSet`

Any idea how to use StringTokenizer to put those tokens into database ?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **Statement.executeUpdate** instead

The executeUpdate method returns an int:

> Returns:
>       either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Comment: ok it works but it only adds one token to database, if I have 2 tokens abc1 and abc2 read from tokenizer.nextToken() it adds only abc2, any idea why?

Comment: The reason is that you cannot reuse a Statement (st). So initialize st inside the while loop instead of outside the while loop.

Comment: is what I did and still no result, same like it was before. I have used `Statement st = null;` and then `st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO "+db+".answersTable(answer) VALUES ('"+tokenizer.nextToken()+"')");` inside the while loop

Comment: ok problem has been solved, needed to assign tokenizer.nextToken() to string `String str = tokenizer.nextToken();`

Comment: also my bad, the sql statement can actually be reused